# One signal push notification did not receive on device,while the application is in closed and device is locked

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

One signal push notification is not receiving in xiaomi Redmi 4,When the application is in closed state and also when the phone is locked.Is there have any method to receive push notification in all time when phone is locked,application is closed and application is in use